# Idiom for Iterable with size() - between Iterable and Collection?

Tags: java, collections, size, idioms, iterable

A `Collection` is an `Iterable` with a size, for which you're allowed to check containment, and add or remove elements. I have objects which inherit `Iterable` and have a size, but not the other features of a Collection. I don't want to implement the `Collection` method with 'Unsupported' exceptions.

Is there some commonly-used middle-of-the-way class between `Iterable` and `Collection` which I can have my objects extend? Something like 'SizedIterable'? Or, more generally, an appropriate idiom?

Note: Yes, it really can't check membership but has a size.

Comment: ...If you can iterate over it, you can check membership just by exhaustive search, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you create your own Interface extending `Iterable`? That way you can define which features you'll add to your custom object.

Something like this perhaps

```
public interface SizedIterable<T> extends Iterable<T> {
    int size();
}
```

Comment: Because I might be reinventing the wheel... if there's a convention, I want to use it.

Comment: I think the convention is what @Gamb is suggesting. I would go for that if I were you

Comment: @MyNameIsTooCommon Thanks for going the extra mile with that edit, I totally missed it and it was neccesary.

Comment: Here is where the collection interface in Java is lacking, if you need your `SizedInterface` to work with existing classes, you need [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.

Long answer: Is there any need for this interface?  What are you planning on using it for?  Unless you have a number of different classes with this same (fairly unusual) property, and some methods that rely on it, I can't think of any apparent need for this interface.

Are you planning on passing this object to standard library functions/classes? Are these methods actually going to call size()?

If so, you'll probably have to just implement Collection, and then have no-ops for add()/remove()/contains()/etc as appropriate.

If not, and you do truly need this interface, extending Iterable is a good approach.

e.g.

```
public interface SizedIterable<T> extends Iterable<T> {
    public int size();
}
```

Comment: Answers by order: I dunno, that's why I asked. I do have a number of different such classes. Not planning to pass it to standard functions except as Iterable. But thanks for the answer...